# Adding a vector of multiple line numbers to my map with a key of words

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

So basically I'm working on a dictionary program that reads in a document and compares it to a list of words and if the words aren't found, I need to add the word to a map with its corresponding line numbers that that word appears on in the document. So I'm trying to do this, but I cannot get the desired results! Here's my code:

```
while (ss >> word)
{
    wordCheck = d.findWord(word, words);
    if(!wordCheck)
    {
        doc.missingMap(word, lineNum);
    }
}
doc.displayMap();
    //this just breaks up each line and checks for the words
```

---

```
    void document::missingMap(string word, int lineNum)
    {
        vector<int> numbers;
        numbers.push_back(lineNum);
        misspelled[word] = numbers; 
    }
```

This is the function in the document calls that would put everything in the map. I don't know if I'm on the right track but if anyone could help me out that would be awesome.
Thanks!

more code in detail

Document class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

class document
{
private:
map<string, vector<int>> misspelled;

public:
document(void);
~document(void);

void missingMap(string word, int lineNum);
void displayMap();
};
```

document.cpp file

```
#include "document.h"


document::document(void)
{
map<string, vector<int> > misspelled;
}
document::~document(void){}

void document::missingMap(string word, int lineNum)
{
//if i declare it here it works but obviously i want to modify it everywhere in the          class
misspelled[word].push_back(lineNum);

}
void document::displayMap()
{
for (map<string, vector<int>>::iterator i = misspelled.begin(); i != misspelled.end(); i++)
{
    cout << i->first << ": ";
    for (vector<int>::iterator j = i->second.begin(); j != i->second.end(); j++)
    {
        cout << *j << endl;
    }
}

}
```

output:

```
debugging: 1
process: 2
removing: 2
programming: 3
process: 4
putting: 4
```

This is how i want it to output but don't know how:

```
debugging: 1
process: 2 4
programming: 3
putting: 4
removing: 2
```

hopefully this helps

Comment: Don't use tab characters within code posted here please!

Comment: As for your last "question" (where you were clever enough to delete it) You can't output `std::vector` instances directly to `std::cout`, use another loop iterating over the vector to output the line numbers detected! You tend to ask questions here awkwardly, presumably it was **only me** getting your context here (told you, I'm **not** your nanny!) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `misspelled[word].push_back(lineNum);` instead.

Change your class declaration as follows:

```
class document
{
private:
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<int> > misspelled;
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ !!!   
public:
    document(void);
    ~document(void);

    void missingMap(string word, int lineNum);
    void displayMap();
};
```

in your `document` class, as you're doing now, you are replacing the `vector` stored in the `misspelled` map with a new one on every call of your `missingMap()` function, instead of adding more line numbers to the map entry (as you are intending I guess).

**Note**
You don't need to explicitly create a `std::vector<int>` instance as an initial entry for any access to `misspelled[word]`, `std::map` handles that for you.

Comment: So I tried that but it still gives me an error. But thats right i want to add a vector of the line numbers that that word appears on. So if it added the word in the map and then later on found that word again, how could i get it to just add the line number to that key? I don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: @user3009714 _'how could i get it to just add the line number to that key?'_ The code I'm showing, does exactly this! You have to be more specific about your particular errors. That was just one semantical error I could immediately spot from the code you're showing in your post. **Edit** your question please, and provide a [minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the errors!

Comment: Kk here is what it says: .push_back must have class/struc/union

Comment: @user3009714 So **ensure** you have `misspelled` map declared exactly as I'm showing!! As I recommended, please **edit your question** to add more information, and a minimal compilable sample that reproduces the problem you have!

Comment: haha okay so if i declare it in that function it works. The thing is have it declared in a class and thats why its giving me problems. im going to post the code so you can see what i mean. by the way thanks for all this help.

Comment: @user3009714 You **have** to declare `misspelled` as member of `document` class as it looks for me, declaring it as a variable within the function is pretty useless!! I'm repeating over and over on things here, you can get pretty well from my answer if you would read it carefully, sigh ...

Comment: i know, i dont want it in the function, i editted the question with more code so you can see.

Comment: Haha im sooooo sorry i just saw what i was doing wrong. You've been great thanks for the help sooooo much, i feel dumb.

Comment: Another quick question, how do i get it to output like this debugging: 1
process: 2 4
programming: 3
putting: 4
removing: 2 the word being the word not found and then its line numbers following it.

Comment: @user3009714 **No!** I'm not your nanny man!! Ask another **[complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** question, including inputs and expected outputs!

Comment: @user3009714 As for your last "question" (where you were clever enough to delete it) You can't output `std::vector` instances directly to `std::cout`, use another loop iterating over the vector to output the line numbers detected! You tend to ask questions here awkwardly, presumably it was **only me** getting your context here (told you, I'm **not** your nanny!) ...

Comment: sorry, yeah im new to this site, normally i can find someone who has had a similar question and can learn from it but i havent see one similar to my situation so i thought i would ask it, so im not familiar with how things should be posted or asked :/

Comment: @user3009714 I hope my last comment, helped you out a bit for your actual problem. I was to give it as a comment on that last question, you have deleted finally. The problem with it was, that it didn't explain your problem self contained. Do not refer to prior posted stuff, it's unlikely someone will lookup and get the context (thus the downvotes). Don't be frightened about downvotes, or take them personally. These are just indicating the quality of your question. You can always wait to see how it develops, and decide at any point of time to delete your question to regain reputation.